# Password Error when logging into POSTGRES on my MAC

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I am having an issue that has been bothering me for some time now. It is with postgres on my mac. I set a password for postgres and I can not remember it for some reason. I have looked up and attempted several different methods for trying to reset the password but none of them are working and I need it fixed as soon as possible.

Here is what my `pg_hba.conf` file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     trust
```

I reset the `local all all trust` and then restarted my postgres server running

```
brew services restart postgres
```

and when i go to try and open postgres on my terminal I get the same password issue:

```
omars-MacBook-Pro:postgres omarjandali$ psql -U postgres -W  -h localhost
Password: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

or

```
omars-MacBook-Pro:~ omarjandali$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You only configured "local" connections which are using Unix domain sockets. But your psql command line tries to establish a TCP connection (`-h ...`), which is not configured in your pg_hba.conf.

You need to use `host` instead of `local`in pg_hba.conf to allow trusted, non-password connections through TCP.

But that is a **really**, really bad idea, because that means that as soon as your Mac is visible on the internet, everybody can connect to your Postgres instance and hack it. This isn't a theoretical threat - there have been numerous posts on this site regarding that.

If you want to allow connections without passwords, at least **only** allow them from "localhost", not from the outside:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             samehost                trust
```

Comment: what command should I use to access the shell... `psql -U postgres` or `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres`

Comment: If you use `-h 127.0.0.1` you need to adjust your pg_hba.conf as I have explained. If you leave out the `-h` you can keep the current file as that initiates a "local" connection as I have explained.

Comment: `omars-MacBook-Pro:postgres omarjandali$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
omars-MacBook-Pro:postgres omarjandali$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` No matter what I run i get a password.

Comment: This is what I have.. `host    all     all             localhost               trust
host    all     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all     all             ::1/128                 trust

`